# Geojson Rendering Problems

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, topojson

I'm trying to put on a map a series of topoJSON, but I came into this strange behaviour of the polygons, see the link below.
If I try to convert them in to geoJSON and to visualise them, i get the same problem.
You can che check [here](http://www.iosonosempreio.com/public/map.html), unfortunately I'm not able to create a JS fiddle due to the ajax call to an external call I have to do. I paste the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>TopoJSON data</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
  path {
  stroke-width:1;
  stroke-opacity:0.25;
  opacity:0.4;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>  
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'MY-ACCESS-TOKEN';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, -80], 5);
d3.json("topoJSON_noPoints.json", function(error, topology) {
  var geodata = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.collection)
  console.log(geodata)
  L.geoJson(geodata, { style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style }).addTo(map);
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Do you ever have a similar problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply, I "workarounded" it.

The problem doesn't seem to be related to the data polygons. It seems to be due to a leaflet bug.
Other users around the web risen up the same issue, for instance look at [this](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/163) where they try to give a solution, which unfortunately didn't work for me. I guess it's probably because I'm not a code-ninja and I can't really get how to use the [**stitch-poles**](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#topology) conversion option.

[Here is a reply to another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420685/4667165), by [@Joac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4249538/joac) who suggests a function based on underscore.js, which worked great for this case of mine. I copy paste his code meshed up with mine down here:

```
function onEachShapeFeature(feature, layer){
    var bounds = layer.getBounds && layer.getBounds();

    if (bounds && (Math.abs(bounds.getEast() + bounds.getWest())) < 0.1) {
        var latlongs = layer.getLatLngs();
        _.each(latlongs, function (shape) {
            _.each(shape, function (cord) {
                if (cord.lng < 0) {
                    cord.lng += 360;
                }   
            }); 
        }); 
        layer.setLatLngs(latlongs);
    }
}
var countries = L.geoJson(geodata, {
        onEachFeature: onEachShapeFeature,
        style: L.mapbox.simplestyle.style
}).addTo(map);
```

If someone could just teach us how to use that famous option and paste a snip here... That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue with the ordering of polygon boundary points in your TopoJSON - [Mapbox has the same issue](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/omnivore-topojson/).

Try re-creating your data set using a tool like [mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/) or [mapstarter](http://mapstarter.com/) - these can take e.g. a [shapefile from an authoritative source](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_nation.html) and export it as TopoJSON.  Better yet, find someone who's done the work for you. [Mike Bostock has a whole US Atlas](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas) with TopoJSON files that work well with Mapbox tiles.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rphv/s4sq551u/) with your code and the [U.S. counties data set](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json). It serves the JSON data set from a Dropbox public folder as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911126/how-to-add-local-json-file-in-jsfiddle). Your JS is modified to access `topology.objects.counties`.

```
    var geodata = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.counties);
```