# Leaflet API - Issue plotting route between long distances

Tags: maps, leaflet, latitude-longitude, great-circle

I am using leaflet API. Trying to draw flight paths based on a series of latitude longitudes. Can someone point me to the solution to the issue below? How can I ensure the path drawn is between the shortest pair of the same locations on the map, rather than two fixed locations with an unwanted straight line between the two route parts?

[image]

Comment: You are hitting antimeridian artifacts. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532496/wrapping-lines-polygons-across-the-antimeridian-in-leaflet-js , as your issue is pretty much the same.

Comment: Check my solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499212/adding-curved-flight-path-using-rs-leaflet-package/43884604) question.